# Mediawiki: ImpotImages script overwriting User and Description

Tags: mediawiki

So I'm migrating a mediawiki from Version 1.17 on Solaris to 1.26.3 on Linux. So when migrate the database and update it via the update.php script, all images in the filelist can't be found by mediawiki, although they are in the images ordner where they have to be. So I was able to fix the problem by reimporting all images via the importImages.php script, but this script overwrites the Uploaduser with "Maintenance script" and the Description with "Importing file".

So how do I restore this information? Or is there a way to uplaod them without overwriting Description and Uploaduser?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to find a Workaround for my Problem. If anyone is facing this problem and is using MySQL (I don't know if it works on other DBMS) try this:

**1.** Dump your Database before you import any images

**2.** Import all images using the importImages.php script (you should use --overwrite)

-> If you are using [simpleSAMLauth](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SimpleSamlAuth) Extension of Mediawiki, disable it before you run the script (uncomment it with # in LocalSettings.php).

**3.** optional: check the filelist in your wiki. The images should be imported with user "Maintenance script" and Description "Importing file".

-> If you get a system Error when accessing the filelist, you should check your permissions on the /images folder (depends which user you used to execute importImages.php).

**4.** Now overwrite your Database with your created Dump from Step 1.

**5.** Check your Filelist and enjoy your perfectly imported images.

I hope this workaround I randomly found helps some people. I know it sounds stupid, but it worked for me.